# Xcode4.3 UIActionSheet causing error message

Tags: ios, xcode, uiactionsheet

The app works perfectly fine when testing but next to `delegate:self` I get...

> Sending 'ViewController *const __strong' to parameter of incompatible
>   type 'id< UIActionSheetDelegate>'

Any help on this is greatly appreciated as ive been on this for days!

My Viewcontroller.h is...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Social/Social.h>

#import "Accounts/Accounts.h"
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>

{
    UIAlertView *objresponseAlert;
}
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *myTextView;

- (IBAction)emailButton:(id)sender;
@end
```

And in my ViewController.m I have....

```
- (IBAction)emailButton:(id)sender {    
    UIActionSheet *actionsheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Title"
                                  delegate:self
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel"
                                  destructiveButtonTitle:nil
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"Email", nil];
    [actionsheet showInView:self.view];
}
```

Comment: You need to make your class conform to `UIActionSheet` Delegate. In header file, make the following changes: `@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,UIActionSheetdelegate>`

Comment: Brilliant! thanks. I had tried typing UIActionSheetdelegate everywhere but didnt realise it was as simple as putting it after a comma! Thanks again!!!

Comment: Typo, should be "UIActionSheetDelegate". The "d" needs to be capital.

Answer (score 5):

This works perfect!

```
// Make Class conform to UIActionSheet delegate
@interface ViewController : UIViewController<MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate,UIActionSheetDelegate>
```